# SQL request with outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, request

[Table DATA DPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBnjL.png)

I work in LibreOffice Data with a table from Access.
The Name of the table is **DPT** (Departement)
The attributs de la table are:

```
**DptNO** -> ID of the departement. 
**dptLib** -> Name of the departement. 
**dptMgr** -> ID of the person who manage the dpt.
**dptAdm** -> id of the Admin departement. (So, a DptNo)
```

I must to give the list of the names of all department  and the name of the departement that administers them.
I tried to do:

```
select d1.dptLib, d2.dptLib
from dpt d1 
join  dpt d2 on d1.dptAdm=d2.dptNo
```

BUT that give me the same names in each column.

Comment: What are the table names? You are currently joining two fields from the same table, which is unnecessary.

Comment: The table is DPT (Departement) and I need the name of the departements(DptLib) with the name of their Administrator (dptLib) because DptAdm give the number of the Departement

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Aren't you getting an error from that?

Comment: No, I use LibreOffice DataBase

Comment: You need to clarify what it is you need from us--we can only take so many shots in the dark with random data pulls

Comment: Sorry : 
Name of Table -> DPT (or Departement)
..........          
dptNo -> id of the departement.        
dptLib -> Name of the depatement.       
dptAdm -> id of the Admin departement.

Comment: please show data from both tables! it is absolutely not clear what you want.

Comment: I must to give the list of all the department names and the name of the department that administers them

Comment: Why did you tag this as mysql if you're not using mysql?

Comment: I thought it was the same

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking to do a self join. Something like this.

```
SELECT d1.dptLib, d2.dptLib
FROM dpt d1
LEFT JOIN dpt d2 on d1.dptAdm = d2.dptNo
```

Comment: I tried that too but it give me the same names in each column

Comment: @Reynaldo I had a typo

Comment: I knew but  it give me the same names in each column

Comment: @Reynaldo Then you messed something up. This is what you want. Show me the data, query, and results that you believe are wrong

Comment: This answer exactly answers your question. See results here: https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/

Comment: It work, My problem was LibreOffice because on SQLite it work well. Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve data from a table you have the option to rename to columns you're getting back. I don't know LibreOffice or what the capabilities of its database might be, but as you have this question tagged for Oracle I'll use Oracle syntax - perhaps if you dig through the documentation for LibreOffice you can determine how to do this in their database:

```
SELECT d1.dptLib AS "Department Name",
       d2.dptLib AS "Administrative Dept."
  FROM dpt d1
  LEFT JOIN dpt d2
    on d2.dptNo = d1.dptAdm
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much I did the same on SQLite and it work. My problem was LibreOffice.

Answer (score -1):

The statement you provided appears to be joining a table to itself.

Comment: Yes,  because the Administrator Department it's in the same table as Departement and I must to have the name of both